# List of length n with p randomly allocated ones else zero

Tags: python, random

What's the shortest way (as in short code) to get a list of length n with p < n randomly allocated ones else zero. Say n = 6 and p = 2, I'd like something like [0,1,0,0,1,0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a list with the correct number of 1s and 0s and then [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it:

```
import random

def random_ones(n, p):
    ls = [1] * p + [0] * (n - p)
    random.shuffle(ls)
    return ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) the indices:

```py
from random import sample

l = [0] * n
idxs = sample(range(n), p)
for idx in idxs:
    l[idx] = 1
```

Or shorter:

```py
from random import sample

idxs = sample(range(n), p)

l = [1 if i in idxs else 0 for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is perhaps not the most efficient way of doing it, but I feel it's a little simpler and easier to understand, so hopefully you'll be able to use it in future. :)

```
from random import randint
list,counter=[],0
for i in range(n):
     list.append(1 if randint(1,2)==2 and counter!=p else 0)
     counter+=1
```